# How to reduce the dimensionality of some 3D points, which are all on the same plane, to 2D in Unity?

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, geometry, triangulation

I have an array of four 3D points (`Vector3[]`), which are all on the same plane. I'm using `Unity` with `C#` and the purpose is to use `2D Traingulator` for these 4 points.

```
using UnityEngine;

Vector3[] vertices3D = new Vector3[] {
    new Vector3(0,10,0),
    new Vector3(50,20,0),
    new Vector3(0,10,30),
    new Vector3(50,20,30)
};
```

Since the [Triangulator](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Triangulator) is only for 2D and all the points are on the same plane,  the approach should be to calculate the basis vectors or the principal components of the plane, but I couldn't find how. I want to reduce the dimensionality of the points to 2D to use `Triangulator` for them in a way that the resulting triangles lie on the plane.

So my desired outputs are only the triangles.

The source code for `Triangulator` is in [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Triangulator), and my goal is to create a mesh for the given points, but as you see the following [sample code](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Triangulator), the input points of the triangulator should be in 2D:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PolygonTester : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        // Create Vector2 vertices
        Vector2[] vertices2D = new Vector2[] {
            new Vector2(0,0),
            new Vector2(0,50),
            new Vector2(50,50),
            new Vector2(50,100)
        };

        // Use the triangulator to get indices for creating triangles
        Triangulator tr = new Triangulator(vertices2D);
        int[] indices = tr.Triangulate();

        // Create the Vector3 vertices
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[vertices2D.Length];
        for (int i=0; i<vertices.Length; i++) {
            vertices[i] = new Vector3(vertices2D[i].x, vertices2D[i].y, 0);
        }

        // Create the mesh
        Mesh msh = new Mesh();
        msh.vertices = vertices;
        msh.triangles = indices;
        msh.RecalculateNormals();
        msh.RecalculateBounds();

        // Set up game object with mesh;
        gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer));
        MeshFilter filter = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter)) as MeshFilter;
        filter.mesh = msh;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a polygon with only 4 points?  There are only 2 ways to split that into two triangles -- just cut across the pair of opposite corners that are closest together.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I have a couple of polygons with 4 points each is a rectangle and representing a wall of a building. As the rectangles should be in a clock-wise order, I think I can't do what you said with a for-loop, because of different positions of the walls.
Eventually, using all the walls, I want to create a 3D mesh representing the building (only walls and without a roof).

Comment: Every `vertices2D[]` rectangle gives 2 triangles with vertex indexes 0,1,2 and 0,2,3 (or alternatively 0,1,3 and 1,2,3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1** - Trivial

If the quad is convex and you know the ordering of the vertices, use `indices = new double[6]{0,1,2,0,2,3};`

**Solution 2** - Triangulate by hand

If the quad is convex but you are unsure about the ordering, test the orientation and adjust the indices.

```
edge1 = vertices3D[1] - vertices3D[0];
edge2 = vertices3D[2] - vertices3D[0];
edge3 = vertices3D[3] - vertices3D[0];
normal12 = Vector3.Cross(edge1, edge2);
normal23 = Vector3.Cross(edge2, edge3);
if (Vector3.Dot(normal12, normal23) > 0)
   indices = new double[6]{0,1,2,0,2,3};
else
   indices = new double[6]{0,1,3,0,3,2};
```

**Solution 3** - Using Triangulator

If the quad is not convex or you really have to use the library Triangulator, transform all vertices such that they are on the XY plane with the first vertex being at `(0,0,0)`.

```
edge1 = vertices3D[1] - vertices3D[0];
edge2 = vertices3D[2] - vertices3D[0];
normal = Vector3.Cross(edge1, edge2).normalized;
rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(normal, new Vector3(0,0,1));
Vector2[] vertices2D = new Vector2[vertices3D.Length];
for (int i=0; i<vertices3D.Length; i++) {
    rotatedVertex = rotation * (vertices3D[i]-vertices3D[0]);
    vertices2D[i] = new Vector2(rotatedVertex.x, rotatedVertex.y);
}
```

I do not recommend using Triangulator for only 4 points forming a wall. However, it should become handy for complex polygons and for non-convex shapes.

Comment: Great! Since the quad is convex, solution 2 worked well. Also, later I found the ordering and thus solution 1 is the best now.

Comment: @Soroosh Great! In case you need it later, I edited solution 2 because it did not compare the correct edges.